# Sub-fields generated by algebraically independent set

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, extension-field

Let $\{a,b,c,d\}$ be algebraically independent set over $\mathbb Q$. Is the following true? I think it is yes but my argument is not strong enough so I am asking what is the easiest way to show it. Here is my question  $$\mathbb Q(a,b)\cap \mathbb Q(c,d)=\mathbb Q$$ where $\mathbb Q(a,b)$ is the smallest sub field the contains $\mathbb Q\cup \{a,b\}$

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes. Any nontrivial common element would describe a nontrivial algebraic dependence.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Could you please show how this can be done ?

Comment: A nontrivial element of $\mathbb{Q}(a, b)$ is a nonconstant rational function $f(a, b)$, a nontrivial element of $\mathbb{Q}(c, d)$ is a nonconstant rational function $g(c, d)$, and if they're equal then $f(a, b) = g(c, d)$ is an algebraic dependence after clearing denominators.

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem touches on some of the hidden difficulty of polynomial rings, in that we are all very familiar with them, but it is often difficult to justify the properties that they "obviously" have. As such, I'll give two solutions - an "easy" and a "hard" one, which involve different levels of rigour, and emphasise different aspects of the problem.

Note that the easy version is not really a solution at all; it is just a restatement of the problem in terms that might make you more comfortable with the answer.

**Easy mode**

Algebraic independence of $\{a, b, c, d\}$ tells us that $\mathbb{Q}(a, b, c, d)$ is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Q}(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ of four-variable rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$. Under this isomorphism, the subfields $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(c, d)$ correspond to $\mathbb{Q}(x_1, x_2)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(x_3, x_4)$ respectively.

Since $\mathbb{Q}(x_1, x_2)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(x_3, x_4)$ are rational functions in different variables, an element in their intersection cannot involve any of the variables, and hence it is rational.

**Hard mode**

Suppose that $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(a, b) \cap \mathbb{Q}(c, d)$.

Since $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(a, b)$, we may express it as

$$\alpha = \frac{f_1(a, b)}{ g_1(a, b)},
$$

where $f_1, g_1$ are polynomials with rational coefficients. Similarly, we have

$$
\alpha = \frac{f_2(c, d)}{g_2(c, d)},
$$
for polynomials $f_2, g_2$. Assume that $\alpha \neq 0$ so that the polynomials $f_i, g_i\neq 0$.

Then we have
$$\frac{f_1(a,b)}{g_1(a,b)} = \frac{f_2(c,d)}{g_2(c,d)},$$

and hence
$$
f_1(a,b)g_2(c,d) = f_2(c,d)g_1(a,b).
$$
Set $p(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = f_1(x_1, x_2)g_2(x_3,x_4) - f_2(x_3,x_4)g_1(x_1,x_2)$ in the polynomial ring $R = \mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]$. Then $p(a, b, c, d) = 0$, so by independence of $a,b,c,d$ we have $p = 0$ in $R$. It follows that

$$
f_1(x_1, x_2)g_2(x_3,x_4) = f_2(x_3,x_4)g_1(x_1,x_2).
$$

View the equation $f_1(x_1, x_2)g_2(x_3,x_4) = f_2(x_3,x_4)g_1(x_1,x_2)$ in the ring $\mathbb{Q}(x_3,x_4)[x_1, x_2]$ of polynomials in $x_1, x_2$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}(x_3, x_4)$.

Write $f_1(x_1, x_2) = \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}x_1^ix_2^j$ and $g_1(x_1, x_2) = \sum_{i,j}b_{ij}x_1^ix_2^j$, where the $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ are nonzero finitely often. Note that $f_1, g_1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2]$ by definition, so the $a_{ij}, b_{ij}$ are all in $\mathbb{Q}$. We have
$$
\sum a_{ij}g_2(x_3,x_4) x_1^ix_2^j = \sum b_{ij}f_2(x_3,x_4)x_1^ix_2^j,
$$
so $a_{ij}g_2 = b_{ij}f_2$ for all $i, j$. In particular, $a_{ij} = 0 \iff b_{ij} = 0$, and when these are nonzero we have
$$
\alpha = \frac{f_2}{g_2} = \frac{a_{ij}}{b_{ij}} \in \mathbb{Q}.
$$

Comment: Qwertiops, This is really help a lot . Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Qwertiops, These topics, algebraically independent and transcendental basis, I did not find a book or lectures that give a lot of information about them. I know, please refer me to them. Also, I do have another question that I did not answer yet which why we really need algebraically independent set why linear independent is not enough

Comment: I would recommend these lecture notes for matters of transcendence: https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/48831. They're quite difficult notes, but definitely give a good set of things to know about. Chapter 8 in particular has a lot of useful stuff about transcendence bases etc.

Comment: As for your question about linear independence, note that $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt[4]{2}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \neq \mathbb{Q}$.